# Understanding binomial expansion

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

Self studying Basic matematics, by Lang.

[image]

Stuck in this section. Does someone know what “select x from k factors” mean?

Comment: You are multiplying $n$ factors, all equal to $(x+y)$. If we were to fully expand this product into sums, we would have a total of $2^n$ terms, one for each choice of $x$ or $y$ in each of the terms. This is what he means by choosing $x$ in $k$ factors, which results in the term $x^ky^{n-k}$.

Comment: Thank you ! What do you mean by “one for each choice of x or y in each of the terms”?

Comment: @F.Zer  From each factor, either an $x$ or $y$ is chosen, giving us two choices.  Since there are $n$ factors, there are $2^n$ terms before like terms are combined.

Comment: Thank you very much, @N. F. Taussig. Unfortunately, there is some needed knowledge I do not have. What I get is: in each factor, _both_ x and y are present. Where does selection process occur?

Comment: In light of your comments, I decided to post an answer that illustrates the problem for the cases $n = 3$ and $n = 4$.  Let me know if you still have questions by posting a comment under my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the examples $(x + y)^3$ and $(x + y)^3$.

By direct computation, we obtain
\begin{align*}
(x + y)^3 & = (x + y)(x + y)^2\\
          & = (x + y)[(x + y)(x + y)]\\
          & = (x + y)[x(x + y) + y(x + y)]\\
          & = (x + y)(x^2 + xy + xy + y^2)\\
          & = (x + y)(x^2 + 2xy + y^2)\\
          & = x(x^2 + 2xy + y^2) + y(x^2 + 2xy + y^2)\\
          & = x^3 + 2x^2y + xy^2 + x^2y + 2xy^2 + y^3\\
          & = x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
(x + y)^4 & = (x + y)(x + y)^3\\
          & = (x + y)(x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3)\\
          & = x(x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3) + y(x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3)\\
          & = x^4 + 3x^3y + 3x^2y^2 + xy^3 + x^3y + 3x^2y^2 + 3xy^3 + y^4\\
          & = x^4 + 4x^3y + 6x^2y^2 + 4xy^3 + y^4
\end{align*}

Now, let's look at what the theorem is saying:  If $n = 3$, we have
$$(x + y)^3 = (x + y)(x + y)(x + y)$$
Each term of the product is formed by selecting either an $x$ or $y$ from each of the three factors.

There are $2^3 = 8$ possibilities:
$$
\begin{array}{c c c c}
\text{first factor} & \text{second factor} & \text{third factor} & \text{product} & \text{simplified product}\\ 
x & x & x & xxx & x^3\\
x & x & y & xxy & x^2y\\
x & y & x & xyx & x^2y\\
x & y & y & xyy & xy^2\\
y & x & x & yxx & x^2y\\
y & x & y & yxy & xy^2\\
y & y & x & yyx & xy^2\\
y & y & y & yyy & y^3
\end{array}
$$
Adding the terms yields $(x + y)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3$.

If $n = 4$, then
$$(x + y)^4 = (x + y)(x + y)(x + y)(x + y)$$
To form, the product, we take either an $x$ or a $y$ from each of the four factors, which gives us $2^4 = 16$ terms.

$$
\begin{array}{c c c c}
\text{first factor} & \text{second factor} & \text{third factor} & \text{fourth factor} & \text{product} & \text{simplified product}\\ 
x & x & x & x & xxxx & x^4\\
x & x & x & y & xxxy & x^3y\\
x & x & y & x & xxyx & x^3y\\
x & x & y & y & xxyy & x^2y^2\\
x & y & x & x & xyxx & x^3y\\
x & y & x & y & xyxy & x^2y^2\\
x & y & y & x & xyyx & x^2y^2\\
x & y & y & y & xyyy & xy^3\\
y & x & x & x & yxxx & x^3y\\
y & x & x & y & yxxy & x^2y^2\\
y & x & y & x & yxyx & x^2y^2\\
y & x & y & y & yxyy & xy^3\\
y & y & x & x & yyxx & x^2y^2\\
y & y & x & y & yyxy & xy^3\\
y & y & y & x & yyyx & xy^3\\
y & y & y & y & yyyy & y^4
\end{array}
$$
Adding the terms yields $(x + y)^4 = x^4 + 4x^3y + 6x^2y^2 + 4xy^3 + y^4$.

Furthermore,
\begin{align*}
(x + y)^3 & = x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3\\
          & = \binom{3}{3}x^3y^0 + \binom{3}{2}x^2y + \binom{3}{1}xy^2 + \binom{3}{0}x^0y^3\\
          & = \sum_{k = 0}^{3} \binom{3}{k}x^ky^{3 - k}
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
(x + y)^4 & = x^4 + 4x^3y + 6x^2y^2 + 4xy^3 + y^4\\
          & = \binom{4}{4}x^4y^0 + \binom{4}{3}x^3y + \binom{4}{2}x^2y^2 + \binom{4}{1}x^1y^3 + \binom{4}{0}x^0y^4\\
          & = \sum_{k = 0}^{4} \binom{4}{k}x^ky^{4 - k}
\end{align*}
Notice that the coefficient of $x^ky^{n - k}$ is equal to the number of times the factor $x$ appears in the product $x^ky^{n - k}$, which is the number of ways we can select $k$ factors of $x$ and $n - k$ factors of $y$ from the $n$ factors in the product $(x + y)^n$.

Comment: Can’t thank you enough. Very grateful for your wonderful explanation. One question: when you say that we take either an x or an y, that “or” is not “exclusive or”, right? I ask because, the product $xxx$ has no $y$.

Comment: Perhaps an illustration will help.  $$(\color{green}{x} + y)(\color{green}{x} + y)(\color{green}{x} + y) = \color{green}{xxx} = \color{green}{x}^3$$ while $$(\color{green}{x} + y)(\color{green}{x} + y)(x + \color{blue}{y}) = \color{green}{xx}\color{blue}{y} = \color{green}{x}^2\color{blue}{y}$$  We have to make a choice in each factor, choosing either $x$ or $y$, which does not preclude taking an $x$ from all three factors or a $y$ from all three factors.